# What is better way to access this. Function.bind vs capturing variables

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

This is a basic question, but this impose an interesting question.
For instance,

```
var Foobar = function(){
    this.baz = 100;    
    this.timer = null;

    this.printLazy = function(){
         
        this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
              console.log(this.baz); //correctly bind this.
        }.bind(this), 1000);
         
    }

}
```

creates a traditional class that we can create instance and call `printLazy` as

```
var myBar = new Foobar();
myBar.printLazy();
```

Now in above code, `printLazy` method sets a timer and inside it, we access `this`.

Same thing can be achived using capturing as,

```
   this.printLazy = function(){
       var self = this; //capture this.
         
        this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
              console.log(self.baz); //correctly bind this.
        }, 1000);
         
    }
```

1. Is one of these methods are better than the other? (Considering efficiency or performance)
2. Can 2nd method can cause memory leaks, if its called lets say 1000 or more times in a quick succession where self would be referenced by other parts inside the function?

Comment: Use arrow functions 
```
var Foobar =()=>{
    let baz = 100;    
    let timer = null;

    this.printLazy =  ()=>{
         
        setTimeout(()=>{
              console.log(baz); //correctly bind this.
        }, 1000);
         
    }

}```

Comment: Yes. Arrow functions uses the correct scope for this. But what I expect is a more theoretical explanation involving es5 style answer involving capturing vs binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is one of these methods are better than the other? (Considering efficiency or performance)

Not really. In your *specific* example, the version using `bind` creates an unnecessary function object (but JavaScript engines are **very** fast at doing that). But it also means that the function you're passing `setTimeout` doesn't close over anything, which is information the JavaScript engine might be able to use to optimize the context attached to it ("closure optimization").

But in modern environments, you'd probably use an arrow function in that situation rather than your `self` option:

```
this.printLazy = function(){
     
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(this.baz);
    }, 1000);
     
}
```

That will log `this.baz` as of when the timer fires. Another option, depending on what you need logged, would be `setTimeout(console.log, 1000, this.baz)`. The difference is that this version will log the value `this.baz` has when the timer is *set up*, not as of when it *fires*. (It also relies on the fact that `console.log`, in most [but perhaps not all] environments, doesn't care what `this` is when you call it.) That's because `setTimeout` passes any extra arguments you give it to the function it calls when it calls it.

> Can 2nd method can cause memory leaks, if its called lets say 1000 or more times in a quick succession where self would be referenced by other parts inside the function?

No. Memory leaks aren't caused by doing things quickly. They're caused by holding onto memory when you don't need it any more and not releasing it. What you're doing doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and are you suggesting using capturing to access this better than Function.bind if es arrow function not supported(IE)? In babel repl it's also the way that babel transform arrow to es5.

Comment: @XPD - Arrow functions close over `this` just like a variable, yes. That **doesn't** mean I'm saying it's "better" to use your second example over your first in obsolete environments without arrow functions, or even in modern environments with arrow functions. I've updated the answer to be clearer about that. `bind` still has a place.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem (in React) recently and found [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/) that shows several options. Below are 3 for your case, with the last one being the recommended option.

**Option 1**
Use arrow functions. But, this will still create a new function every time `printLazy` is called.

```js
this.printLazy = function(){
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.baz); //correctly bind this.
    }, 1000);
}
```

**Option 2**
Create second function and bind it in the constructor, which still has performance drawbacks.

```js
var Foobar = function(){
    constructor() {
        this.printLazyCallback = this.printLazyCallback.bind(this)
    }

    printLazyCallback() {
         console.log(this.baz); //correctly bind this.
    }
}
```

**Option 3 (the one you should use)**
Create second function as class prop arrow function

```js
var Foobar = function(){
    printLazyCallback = () => {
         console.log(this.baz); //correctly bind this.
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially You are correct and upvoted, unfortunately I was expecting an es5 style answer.

Comment: Not sure if this works, but you can try to do this outside of it: Foobar.printLazyCallback = Foobar.printLazyCallback.bind(Foobar).